# Visual Assist не адаптирует подсветку синтаксиса под тёмную тему Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019, settings, syntax, visual-studio-extensions, highlighting

Все здравствуйте.

После ряда экспериментов с настройками Visual Assist'a его подсветку синтаксиса заклинило на светлой теме Visual Studio. При включении тёмной темы цвета переменных, функций и пр. не меняются на более тёплые тона. Я пробовал удалять Visual Assist и чистить его настройки в реестре - не помогает. Коллеги, использующие тёмную тему Visual Studio и дефолтные цветовые настройки Visual Assist'a, выложите, пожалуйста, скриншот его окна настроек для подсветки синтаксиса. Я просто скопирую ваши цвета. Вот как это выглядит у меня.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня вот так. Никогда на светлую тему не переключал. Настройки в этом месте не трогал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: КоВадим, огромное спасибо. Это именно то что нужно. Я полдня трахался, пытаясь по памяти восстановить эти цвета.